# Azure Scale-set how to monitor memory utilization

Tags: azure

How do I monitor memory utilization for Azure Scale-set default metrics is only CPU Disk and network. Why does Azure not provide memory utilization by default

Comment: I find this fact to be absurd.  Why should memory be so difficult to access using crazy configs.. MS needs to get their head out of their socialist arse

Answer (score 0):

in order to enable custom metrics (that includes memory utilization) for the Virtual Machine Scale Set you need to modify the ARM template.

Documentation:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/collect-custom-metrics-guestos-resource-manager-vmss
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-faq#is-there-a-virtual-machine-scale-set-template-example-that-integrates-with-azure-monitor-logs